# Java 6 Hardware Acceleration on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, hardware-acceleration

I have a java application I wrote that loads up a TTF font and uses the `drawString` method from Graphics2D. This gets called every 50ms with the x and y positions changing each time to make the text move. When I run the program on Windows, I get 0-1% CPU usage, but on Mac I get about 75% usage. This Windows machine does have a better CPU but there's no way there should be that big of a difference. I think it has to do with Hardware Acceleration and I want to know how enable it. I found some [Mac specific Java properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html), but none of them lowered my CPU usage. Any ideas how to increase Java 2D performance on OS X? Thanks.

EDIT1: I thought that these properties would help but they didn't.

`System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");`
`System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz","true");`          `System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.EnableQ2DX","true");`

EDIT2: <s>You can download the project source and byte code here: http://drop.io/ExampleScreenSaver</s>

EDIT3: Since drop.io no longer exists, I uploaded the project to [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/example-screen-saver-java/source/checkout). Now you can browse the code without downloading it. I still have no idea how to approach this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, but I'm fairly certain it's not the computer. Both machines have Core 2 Duos: Windows is 3.0GHz, Mac is 2.0GHz. Windows has 2GB of RAM, Mac has 4GB. Windows is using integrated Intel graphics, Mac is using Nvidia 9400m. Windows runs it as expected, Mac hits 75% every time. Increasing the refresh time from 50ms to 500ms obviously doesn't look smooth anymore and the Mac is still at about 50% CPU usage.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Keep in mind that the JVM on Macs is supplied by Apple, while on Windows you use a JVM of another supplier (most likely Sun). Different JVM implement things differently, so this might be completely "normal" behaviour.

Comment: I understand the JVM is supplied by Apple, but I don't think this situation is "normal." I'm not doing anything 3D so the graphics should be able to handle it fine. I believe it has to do with hardware acceleration being enabled on Windows by default and probably hidden somewhere in a property for Mac. I don't think anyone would agree that a simple 2D screensaver running at 75% CPU usage on a Core 2 Duo is "normal." I'll post an example soon.

Comment: Apple has a pretty active mailing list, available here : http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/java-dev. Apple staff maintains an active presence. Your problem can most likely find a solution there.

Answer (score 2):

Run the profiler in "jvisualvm" to identify where the time goes.

Comment: I ran jvisualvm and used the profiler on the CPU. It's exactly what I expected: the draw method self time is 89% and the next highest is the paint method (I used @override) is the next highest at 7%. This is expected because the I have a swing timer that calls the paint method every 30ms, and for each call to the paint method the draw method is called on every object to make them move a couple pixels. But back to my original question, how can I make this run like it does on Windows (with very low CPU usage)?

Comment: Can you make a small self-contained example I can play with on my Mac?

Comment: Ok I made a small example with just the letter Z moving across the screen. The results are identical: 70-90% CPU usage on the Mac and 0-2% CPU usage on Windows XP.

Comment: I had a look at the code in the example linked to in the question.  I see the same behaviour as you do on a Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro.  Various hints to the JVM did not improve performance.  My guess right now is that JVM has to convert the pixels sent to the screen hence slowing down.

Comment: @I82Much: I put the example in the original post.
@Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Thanks for looking. I just need to find a way to force Java to use the video card to take the load off the CPU.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.  I am not that much into Graphics2D.

Answer (score 1):

Apple JVM font handling is specific to MacOS X. For instance, if a glyph is not found for a character in the current font, the JVM looks for another font to display the character. Also, antialiasing is enabled by default (you should check that you have it enabled on Windows if you want to compare).
I am not surprised Apple's implementation is using more CPU.

Comment: I have tried AA in both Windows and OS X. On both OS's, AA does increase CPU usage but it bumps up from 0% to about 5% on Windows and from 75% to about 100% on OS X. As far as the font not working properly, I think that is not part of the problem since the font works on both OS's. Did you try running the code?

Comment: I just tried on my Mac (without the font), and I can only confirm what you wrote : 75% CPU, mostly spent by sun.java2D.SunGraphics2D.drawString(). I don't know how to improve that. I'm afraid the implementation is just not optimized... I would try using an image buffer to avoid calling drawString too often in the example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL can be enabled when calling java e.g.

*java -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true MyJavaGame*

Too enable opengl from inside your java application

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
```

Not sure how this pans out on the iOS / Linux / Android and may require more looking into.

Comment: I wrote that in my original question and mentioned it didn't work.

Comment: Damn.  I got around it by doing software rendering.

Blitting to an array and use that as a source for a buffered image and then draw that with nano timing and sync to keep it smooth too 60 frames.